# findViewById in Fragment cannot obtain its View(on a null object reference)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container,false);
    Button btn_new = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_new);
   //Button btn_new = getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_new);I have tried this code as well, but it still failed.
    btn_new.setText("text");
    return rootView;
}

//onViewCreated() cannot resolve this problem.
//@Override
//public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//    Button btn_new =getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_new);
//}
```

I used "import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;"

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.flightnavigation.AirportsFragment.onCreateView(AirportsFragment.java:90)

Comment: Are you inflating the correct layout file `fragment_map.xml` in your `AirportsFragment.java`? And make sure `btn_new` is in `fragment_map.xml`

Comment: Oh. thanks, a stupid carelessness